# Setup installer Visual Studio C# Express

Tags: c#, installation

is there any way to create a setup installer for a project in Visual Studio C# 2010 Express Edition? I know just must go to New> New Project and then click on "Other Projects" and then Select Visual Studio Installer.

But these options are not appearing on the express edition, so is there any way to install these options or get to do the installer? Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Which version (2010, 2012, etc.) of VS?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET sorry I just edited my post. It's about 2010 version.

Comment: Why you don't use  Visual Studio Community 2013(http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx). You can install plugin like this (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d)

Comment: @octavioccl So, it is free and it will allow me to do what I need to do?

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio Comunnity 2013 is free. Installing that extension (Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects ) you include a new type of project in Visual Studio Community that let you create an setup installer

Answer (score 1):

Try [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)

It allows you to create Windows Setup easily.

Comment: The question didn't ask for a recommendation for install creators. (If it had, it would be off-topic here.) It asks a specific question about a specific version of Visual Studio. (Product recommendations are *never* acceptable answers here, and neither are answers that consist almost entirely of a link to an external site.)